# Extract latest data from dataframe using latest dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Date           Sub  Value
10/24/2020  A   1
9/18/2020   A   2
9/21/2020   A   3
9/13/2020   A   4
9/20/2020   A   5
```

I want to extract the data using latest date from the dataframe.
I was using the following formula, but the output is different

```
df = df.Date.max()
```

Output: `2020-10-24 00:00:00`.

The output which i am looking for is

```
Date           Sub  Value
10/24/2020     A    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and `[[]]` for output one row `DataFrame` - get only one row by first maximal `datetime`:

```
df1 = df.loc[[df.Date.idxmax()]]
```

Or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare `max` - then get multiple rows if more like `1` max values:

```
df1 = df[df.Date.eq(df.Date.max())]
```

Answer (score 4):

To get multiple rows matching the same `max` value, you can do this:

```
In [2679]: df[df.Date == df.Date.max()] 
Out[2679]: 
        Date Sub  Value
0 2020-10-24   A      1
```